# javascript to check when the browser window is closed

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know any way that I can use javascript to check when the browser window is closed and pop-up a confirmation dialog to ask whether the user is confirm to exit the browser or change his mind to stay?

Comment: By browser window do you mean the page window or the entire browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser window close event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var e = e || window.event;

  //IE & Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Are you sure?';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'Are you sure?';
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Comment: That should probably be 'return confirm("Are you sure? ...");'.

Comment: @Anon nope, confirm() returns a boolean, your handler for onbeforeunload is required to return a string.

Comment: Well, that's a peculiar behavior. Goes to show how often I've used it!

Comment: I am down-voting this because if you try going to another link on the page, you see "Are you sure?"

Comment: there is no difference between navigating away from a page and closing a browser window as far as the DOM is concerned. @ElHaix

Comment: Yes... That's the problem. So what if you have kinks on that page, etc.? User will be shown the pop-up if they click on a link.  It should only occur if they close the page. I got around this by checking history on new browser page load but that's weak as they could go to other sites before the checking page.

Comment: I am using this script for exit popup and popup is as i need... but i need only on exit the site not when user change page of click any other link ...

Comment: beforeunload is no longer supported in ios. any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) encourages listening to the `onbeforeunload` *event* and/or adding an event listener on `window`.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {}, false);
```

You can also just populate the `.onunload` or `.onbeforeunload` properties of `window` with a *function* or a *function reference*.

Though behaviour is not standardized across browsers, the *function* may return a value that the browser will display when confirming whether to leave the page.

Answer (score 1):

If the browser remains running after the page is closed, and if the browser processes the "***onbeforeunload***" event of the body element (sometimes it's disabled), and if the browser allows popup windows or mesage boxes and the ability to return false from that event to prevent the page change, then it's possible.

For an example, start typing a comment on any stackoverflow page with Javascript enabled and then navigate away from that page.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
function closeWin(){
 var exit = confirm("Do you want to leave this window?");  
     if(exit==true){
        //do something before closing;
     }
}    

body onbeforeunload="closeWin()"
```

Answer (score 1):

This works too, unless for IE8

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function (e) {
        // code to execute when browser is closed
        e.$.post("func.php", { action: 'action', id_userMsg: '<?php echo $id_user; ?>' });      

    });
```