# End Session on browser/tab close

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have browsed through out the internet. I can't find a proper solution for this. Is there a proper way to kill/end session when browser or tab is closed without logging off?

I have tried all the codes in javascript that I found on internet. None of them work.

All my users use IE only. So the code can work for that alone. Any tech is fine with me ie, javascript, jquery, ajax. Is there any solution for this? I know HTTP is stateless, browser event is client side and all that. But someone should have a working code for this. Please help.

Comment: call your logout page via ajax on window.onbeforeunload event

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443503/how-to-run-javascript-code-on-window-close

Answer (score 1):

There is no working code for this. The only 100% working way, especially in case of IE – using keep-alive requests and clear session by timeout on user inactivity.