# How can we expire website user session on closeing of browser in asp with c#?

Tags: asp.net, session

In my website, I am maintaining `session["login"]=1` on successful login of user. I want to expire the session on closing of browser in ASP with C#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582615/end-session-on-browser-tab-close

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21580566/304683