# Prevent user to leave my page in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my form, I have an unshowy modal. I open the modal if the user clicks on my "leave image" and I ask if he wants to leave.

Is that possible in JavaScript (Jquery ?) to "stop" the reloading or the page change to show my modal and continue the action (Reload, Next page, Prev page, etc...) if the user says yes?

I tried:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    return 'message to show';
});
```

But I don't want to open the browser popup, I want mine ^^.

Comment: think this is a question that has been asked many, many times. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443503/how-to-run-javascript-code-on-window-close

Comment: "But i don't want to open the browser popup, i want mine ^^." No, that's not possible!

Comment: Please. Don't. The user should always be in charge.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way of stopping user from leaving the page. Only thing that can be done is confirm window.

Comment: Ok, how do you do that then?

Comment: @giker only straight answer I get.

Answer (score 3):

There is both `window.onbeforeunload` and `window.onunload`, which are used differently depending on the browser. You can ask them either by setting the window properties to functions, or using the `.addEventListener`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   // Do something
}
```

// OR

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e){
   // Do something
}, false);
```

Usually, `onbeforeunload` is used if you need to stop the user from leaving the page (ex. the user is working on some unsaved data, so he/she should save before leaving). `onunload` isn't supported by Opera, as far as I know, but you could always set both.