# Facebook logout onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

In my AngularJS application I use the Facebook SDK. 
When I use `FB.logout()` on the logout button click it works properly:

```
  $scope.logout = function() { 
    FB.logout() 
  }
```

But I also want to logout from Facebook on window close. I do the following:

```
  $window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    FB.logout()
   }
```

As you can see I do the same in both cases. However, second one does not work.

Could someone tell me, why? And how to make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `null` from `onbeforeunload` function. [As mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445846/1227747)

So this should work.

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   FB.logout()
   return null;
}
```