# how to call a function when user left website

Tags: php, ajax

Because any user of my website has a `username` - `password` and a `TOKEN`, 
after do login, the user has a `TOKEN`.  Any user can not login at this time by that `username` and `password` until the `TOKEN` expires.

to expire that `TOKEN` when user left website, is it possible to call a php function after/before leaving user?

If not, what should i do? is it possible to call ajax ?

How can I find out if the user has left the site?

Comment: see this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443503/run-javascript-code-on-window-close-or-page-refresh

Comment: by `onbeforeunload` event, when user refresh is it called ?

Comment: yes, it is considered a page leave