# Capture window close event using Jquery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to refresh parent tab that opened a window. In order to do that I am trying to catch `close event` of the tab so that once I catch the event, I will refresh parent window and this tab will get closed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
     alert("test");
    };
</script>
```

Whatever I do, I always get this message. 
[image]

If I comment `return  "test"` I don't get the message, that means the code does something which eventually causes the given alert.
How to catch the tab/current window close event in JS or jquery?

**PS: Checked solutions on [Run JavaScript code on window close or page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443503/run-javascript-code-on-window-close-or-page-refresh) and [How to capture the browser window close event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/how-to-capture-the-browser-window-close-event) , they are not working anymore. Probably, newer versions have something to do with this.**

Comment: you only have `onbeforeunload` event available for this

Comment: tried `$(window).unload(function() {  alert("test");
            }` but no luck

Comment: what do you want to do? why do you use alert inside the callback?

Comment: it's just for testing purpose, I will reload the parent page instead of alert @Maximus

Comment: That is not possible for security reasons. `alert` is blocked on Chrome when called on `onbeforeunload` event.

Comment: [The HTML5 specification states that calls to window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Comment: tried..not working @Maximus

Comment: @Amden I see, excluding alert test of the things can be done right?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo, I don't understand what's not working

Comment: @Maximus I tried to alert, i didn't alert, it should have alerted. I tried to update value of a field on close event, it didn't work..

Comment: Try to put the `debugger;` statement into the callback for testing purposes and open your dev tools :)

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo, I posted a link which said the `HTML5` says that `alert` call could be ignored, and it's probably is. Do you want to show some message before window close?