# Javascript alert on page load and alert on page exit

Tags: javascript, html

Working on a project for class and I want a javascript event that gives a pop-up on a page load and a pop up when the user navigates away. I try to handle it with `onload` and `onunload` events embedded directly in my html but it doesn't appear to be working on chrome and on internet explorer I seem to only get the unload message. The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>teest</title>
    <!-- [if lt IE 9]>
    <script src = "http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif] -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/contact.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- viewport tag configuration -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" />
  </head>
  <body onload = "alert('Even if you aren't interested, please give our design some feedback as we would like to stay current.')" onunload = "alert('Thank you for your time and consideration!')">
        <header class = "head">
          <h1>
          <img src="img/coa.png" display="inline-block"  height="150px" float="left"/>
          other stuff</h1>
          <p>stuffsy</p>
        </header>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run JavaScript code on window close or page refresh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443503/run-javascript-code-on-window-close-or-page-refresh)

Comment: The [documentation for the unload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload) states that "UI interactions are ineffective (window.open, alert, confirm, etc.)", so you can't use alert in onunload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape your quotes in the alert.
Your current string is

```
'Even if you aren't interested, please give our design some feedback as we would like to stay current.'
```

And your have to change it to

```
'Even if you aren\'t interested, please give our design some feedback as we would like to stay current.'
```

So it will recognize your string the right way

Comment: Do you have any idea why the `onunload()` event doesn't appear to work in chrome?

Comment: Chrome automatically blocks alert messages in onunload event
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihX2X.png

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. I need to find a work-around for it because my assignment demands it.