# How do I create a javascript timer that's not associated with a window

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a situation where I call a bit of javascript and it needs to do some housekeeping of data that is not associated with the current window after a small period of time has elapsed. However it seems that if I start a timer using `window.setTimeout`, it'll be cancelled if the window gets closed. This is something I really don't want to happen. Is there a parent window of all windows that won't get closed till the browser quits, or anything else I can use.

Comment: If the window is closed what do you want it to clean up?

Comment: What do you mean by clean up? What is it that you want to clean?

Comment: it's data that is not associated with the window on which I want to do some housekeeping (in this specific case, I don't want to write the data to disk every time it's updated, but would rather write it back after a few seconds when updates have stopped)

Comment: What do you mean write it back to disk? In an AJAX call? If that's the case, you should still make the AJAX call and have your _server_ hold on to the data, and use a timer there to write it back to disk.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the window.onUnload event or the window.onbeforeunload event to do whatever it is you need to do.  Take a look at this previous question [Run JavaScript code on window close or page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443503/run-javascript-code-on-window-close-or-page-refresh)

Comment: that's a thought but i really want to avoid any dependencies on a window as I'm trying to put this code into a module

Comment: @TomTanner In the browser, all Javascript is associated with a window, except maybe browser extensions.