# Equivalent of atexit() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, browser, termination

I tried searching it up on the internet but I don't find anything relevant.

Is there a way to call a function upon program termination in Javascript similar to the functionality of atexit() in C++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run JavaScript code on window close or page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443503/run-javascript-code-on-window-close-or-page-refresh)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: because you tag browser.