# How can I know the user closes tab or browser in html?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I´m working on a webapp MVC and want to know when the user closes the browser tab, in order to destroy his session. I´m working with jsp (html, js) and java for the internal code. Some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.onunload` function from javascript

```
window.unload = function () {
  //doSomething
}
```

or add an eventlistener to the `unload` event of the window in following way:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function() {
  // doSomething
})";
```

Have a look at the full docs on more details [onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload) and [unload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload) event.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this link and put your ajax session destroy there ->** [Run JavaScript code on window close or page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443503/run-javascript-code-on-window-close-or-page-refresh)

*after the Ajax call, you can easily get the session and invalidate/remove it!*