# Save cookies/session when window close and load when open

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im creating a browser with selenium in nodejs

but i need save session/cookie WHEN window close

i tried it:

```
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const fs = require('fs');

async function example() {
  let driver = await new Builder()
  .forBrowser('firefox')
  .build();
  await driver.get('http://www.facebook.com');

  // fs.appendFile('server.log', driver.manage().getCookies().toString(), function (err) {
  //   if (err) return console.log(err);
  //   console.log('Appended!');
  // });
}

example();
```

but its open and save, i need save WHEN browser is closed, i thought in something like: `driver.addEventListener('on-close', function() { 
fs.appendFile('server.log', driver.manage().getCookies().toString(), function (err) {
  //   if (err) return console.log(err);
  //   console.log('Appended!');
 })` but i dont found nothing about "when close"

Thanks for help =)

Comment: Try [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: yeah, but my ask is: how can i get this event "when-close" ?

Comment: Then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443503/run-javascript-code-on-window-close-or-page-refresh) should help, sorry for misunderstanding =)

Comment: i tried but dont work =(

Comment: I think its a time issue. I tried to setTimeout on my test page and it didn't save anything when I closed the page. Maybe if its taking that much time, then it's better to save cookies every time something changes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.quit(function())
```