# How can I run javascript code only when page is fully unloaded?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to run a certain piece of code ONLY when the page is exited. I have tried this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    new Notification('Window unloaded');
    return true;
}
```

However, if the user presses 'cancel,' then the notification still shows up. How can I make it so that the code only runs if the page is fully exited?

Comment: Service workers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run JavaScript code on window close or page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443503/run-javascript-code-on-window-close-or-page-refresh)

Comment: No, that does not answer my question. Whenever reload the page, if I press "Cancel", then the code still runs (I get a notification). I want the code to only run when the page is fully unloaded (exited).