# How to run a method when the window closes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering how I can run a method when a window or tab **closes**.  I've tried using the following...

```
window.onclose = () => {
  // execute function
}
```

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => {
  // execute function
}
```

but both of these only fire when I *refresh* the page **not** when I close it.
Any help would be very appreciated thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run JavaScript code on window close or page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443503/run-javascript-code-on-window-close-or-page-refresh)

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I have already tried this.

Comment: I don't see anything in your question about trying the `visibilitychange` event as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52412486/215552)...

Comment: @HereticMonkey, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible anymore.

Newer browsers doesn't support it anymore.