# window.unload() won't work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to alert something out after closing page.

A simple `window.unload` example as below :

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript">
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
$(window).unload( function () { 
    alert("Bye now!"); 
});
```

**P.S :**

I have tried javascript too, but doesn't alert anything out !

**test.js**

```
window.onunload = function() {
    alert("Bye now!");
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript to check when the browser window is close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805463/javascript-to-check-when-the-browser-window-is-close)

Comment: How about `window.onbeforeunload`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Most browsers prevent `alert` in `unload`.  The best you can do is to use an `onbeforeunload` handler that returns a string - the browser will show that string to the user:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Bye now!";
};
```

[**Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/GL2Dg/)

Comment: Thank You. `onbeforeunload` working like a charm. But just on FireFox !!! doesn't work on Chrome!!!

Comment: @HamedKamrava: Are you returning the string, rather than calling `alert`?  See my updated answer and the linked demo.

Comment: It Working like a charm :). tnx

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you testing this code in ?

If you check the following link from W3School, Opera and Chrome do not support it. [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp)

And a working example for onbeforeunload is to use jquery as following :

```
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
           // Do stuff
    });
```

(I was going to comment this last bit on the above post but I cannot yet comment :'( )

Answer (score 0):

Use `body` or `document` instead of window.