# Onunload doesn't work in JS

Tags: javascript

```
window.onunload = function()
{
    confirm("close the window?")
}
```

Why don't I have the confirm window coming out when closing a window?

Comment: window.onunload is not universally supported and where it is, its implementation can vary. Don't rely on it.

Comment: Try to use "onbeforeunload" instead. Don't use `confirm`, just return a string from the event handler. The browser will take care of the confirmation message box all by itself, presenting the message you returned from the event handler

Answer (score 0):

Presumably it is to prevent pages from repeatedly preventing you from closing a page. With the [`beforeunload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/beforeunload), you can, however, get what is, in most modern browsers, a non-customizable or only partly customizable dialog prompting the user whether to leave or not.

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers not support window.unload.

Please view this link.

[window.onbeforeunload and window.onunload is not working in Firefox , Safari , Opera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645011/window-onbeforeunload-and-window-onunload-is-not-working-in-firefox-safari-o)

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers prevent the use of alert/confirm in onunload. 
Instead use an onbeforeunload handler that returns a string:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Don't go!";
};
```

This will then be presented to the user in a dialogue box.

See also: [window.unload() won't work in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790256/window-unload-wont-work-in-jquery)