# How to detect browser tab close event with react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to detect browser tab / browser close event with react js to detect user log out action (call api). I have tried using `beforeunload` event as

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {

      let confirmationMessage = "o/";

      (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE

      console.log("logout !");
      return confirmationMessage; //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
    
    });
  });
```

It works fine if user closes the tab but the issue is it is also firing when user `reload` the page which I dont want for log out action, I've tried searching and tried these solutions as well but no work for me. Are there any solutions to detect only when browser / browser tab closes and not reload ?

[Detect browser close event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30449668/11866037)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5593734/11866037

[Warn user before leaving web page with unsaved changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7317273/11866037)

Answer (score 3):

you missed to add the return function in your `useEffect` which runs the cleanup i.e `componentWillUnmount`.

Your code will look something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {

       window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {

      let confirmationMessage = "o/";

      (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE

      console.log("logout !");
      return confirmationMessage; //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
    
    });
   }
   
  });
```