# Check if user is leaving the page js

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onbeforeunload

I tried onbeforeunload event but it's not working when leaving the page it's only working when I reload but every thing works fine on edge. 
I think Chrome have changed somethings in configuration.
Is there a way to fix that or another method?

```
onbeforeunload = function(){
    return("bye");
}
```

AND is there a way I can check if user is closing the page or redirecting to another url with out firing on reloading or  can I not do that?

Comment: You can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805463/javascript-to-check-when-the-browser-window-is-close

Comment: @AmrLabib not working!

Answer (score 3):

Even when using [JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/unload/), a framework with the objective *cross browser compatibility*, they say:

> The exact handling of the unload event has varied from version to version of browsers. For example, some versions of Firefox trigger the event when a link is followed, but not when the window is closed. In practical usage, behavior should be tested on all supported browsers and contrasted with the similar beforeunload event.

[Source](https://api.jquery.com/unload/)

So you have to accept an inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: So how can  I handle that, I have a function necessarily need to know if user is leaving or redirecting to another page

Comment: depending on your site, at least the part with the redirect is easy by adding a click handler to every link

Comment: Ok but what about leaving the page?!

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return "Bye";
}
```

As you need to attach the event to the `window`